# Fit two textView in LinearLayout next to an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="2dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_album"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"  
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
        android:padding="5dp"    
        />
   <LinearLayout 
       style="@style/fill_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_album"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true">
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/album_title"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
         android:singleLine="true"                           
         android:textColor="@color/black"            
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         />

     <TextView        
        android:id="@+id/picts_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        android:textColor="@color/black"        
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which gives me this image:

[image]

I dont know why I dont get the title of the album and next the number of picts.

Well, I did something using layout_weight property as:

```
<TextView
         android:id="@+id/album_title"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
         android:singleLine="true"                           
         android:textColor="@color/black"            
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         />

 <TextView        
    android:id="@+id/picts_number"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
    android:textColor="@color/black"      
    android:layout_weight="1"  />
```

And I dont really know why, I get now the number, next to the title, as

[image]

Could someone tell me:

1. Why I dont get the number in the 1st scenario, but I do in the 2nd.
2. How to expand the text all the width of the Linearyout, so the
       second Text "Smartphones..." doesnt get stretch, but fits its
       parent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `width = 0dip` and weigth = 1. I did it!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="2dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_album"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"  
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
        android:padding="5dp"    
        />
   <LinearLayout 
       style="@style/fill_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_album"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"       
       android:id="@+id/album_details">
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/album_title"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
         android:singleLine="true"                           
         android:textColor="@color/black"            
         android:layout_marginRight="30dp"           
         android:textSize="17sp"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         />

     <TextView        
        android:id="@+id/picts_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        android:textColor="@color/black"      
        android:layout_weight="0"  
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it with a FrameLayout rather than a RelativeLayout. It's really easier to build your layout with this. Something like this, but with size and style adaptation :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_album"        
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"  
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:padding="5dp"    
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/album_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"               
        android:singleLine="true"                           
        android:textColor="@color/black"            
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    />

    <TextView        
        android:id="@+id/picts_number"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"                      
        android:textColor="@color/black"        
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Bourbon, but I would like to understand RelativeLayout and LinearLayout.

Comment: No problem :-) Don't forget this link : http://developer.android.com/design/index.html